# How to apply the correct edit page URL when create new page by Experience Manager

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-manager

After we install DXA example, we give it a test URL `dxaexample.mydoamin.com`. When we create a new article page, the URL inside the Experience Manager side is wrong, but the page do create success.

Here are the steps:

1. Page type located at folder root\page-types.
2. Based on this page type we create another page abc.aspx which
   located at folder root\news
3. Click button create, page will be created at folder
   root\news\abc.aspx, but the experience manager editor will point to
   root\page-types\abc.aspx, which seems follow the page type location.

Once we click save, the edit will try to load URL
`http://contentmanager-lab.mydomain.org:81/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=editing-site&url=%23url%3Dhttp://dxaexample.mydomain.com/page-types/article1.html`

Which is wrong. The correct URL should be: 
`http://contentmanager-lab.mydomain.org:81/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=editing-site&url=%23url%3Dhttp://dxaexample.mydomain.com/news/article1.html`

Any idea where we should change to apply the correct link?

Comment: Could you by any change be using SDL Web 8, not including the Cumulative Update? This sounds like a defect found on SDL Web 8, which is fixed in SDL Web 8 CU1, or SDL Web 8.5 for that matter.

Comment: After apply the fix, the URL issue is fixed. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1):

Please read few SDL [Experience Manager implementation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13#docid=GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13&filename=GUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E7D54121-70A2-4FA6-A516-8ADB8E45AC13)

Comment: We do went through this documentation before. The situation here is: page type located at folder root\_page-types. Based on this page type we create another page abc.aspx which located at root\news, after click button create, page will be created at folder root\news\abc.aspx, but the experience manager editor will point to root\_page-types\abc.aspx. which will cause page not exist issue.